# Grub can't find Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

Using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS after upgrading from 12.04. I have 3 hard drives: sda has Windows, sdb has Ubuntu, sdc is a non-bootable backup drive. Before I upgraded to 14.04, I had an option to boot Windows 7 or Ubuntu, and now I can only see Ubuntu. Yes, I've tried os-prober and grub-update to no avail. I have also done boot-repair, and you can see the output [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8479372/). Does anyone have an idea as to how I can add a Windows 7 boot option? (Also, gparted shows that it's a healthy bootable drive on sda, I just can't get it into the grub menu.) I am also aware that sda is BIOS and sdb is UEFI, but this was never a problem before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this by doing a chainload on the correct sdX that holds Windows 7.

I recommand you grub-customizer or kde-grub editor tool to do it.

Comment: Yes, I figured that, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Care to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I used to do it manually before Grub 1.99, but here's the way to make it so with Grub customizer: 1.Add a new entry; 2.Put it as a chainloader; 3. You should normally have installed Windows on sda1, so set it.; 4. Save. Next is what the source should look like:
savedefault
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
chainloader +1
; Note that even if Windows is installed in sda2, sda1 is where the bootloader is.